# How to change UInavigationBar color inside an UICollectionViewHeader with category?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uicollectionview, categories

I have an application with multiple view controllers. I created categories to change colors of each element (UIButton, UILabel, UIView etc).

Everything is going fine for all elements but one. I can't find out how to change the tint of the UINavigationBar of a reusableView (header) in a CollectionView.

I managed to change the color of other UINavigation bars that are not in a collectionView.

What I am supposed to do? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out. Simply had to use: `-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{ 
[self.navigationbarname categorycolormethod]; 
}`

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of `UINavigationBar`, use this code:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: Thanks Norbert. I know how to change the UINavigationBar tint, my issue is that I don't know how to change the UInavigationBar tint when it's inside a reusableView of a UICollectionView. Also, I need to use categories to allow users to change the color theme of the app.